# Why aren't these hyphenation \patterns applied in lualatex?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm compiling the following code in *lualatex*, and looking at the console log for the output of `\showhyphens`:

```
\language=99
\lefthyphenmin=1
\righthyphenmin=1
%\patterns{a9b ba}  % L1: ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
%\patterns{a9b}  % L2: ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
%\patterns{ba a9b}  % L3: ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
\patterns{ba} \patterns{a9b}  % L4: babababababa
\showhyphens{babababababa}
\makeatletter\@@end
```

I don't understand the difference between L3 and L4, in particular why aren't there any hyphens in L4?

Comment: well that's a good question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle One for the luatex list?

Comment: @egreg yes I think so

Comment: L4 is the only one you show with two patterns but that isn't the problem, this works`\patterns{zx} \patterns{a9b}` so it is some interaction with the overlapping patterns supplied as two `\patterns`. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed: if we try `\patterns{a9b}\patterns{ba}` the output is `ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba` as expected. Also `\patterns{ab} \patterns{b9a}` gives `b-ab-ab-ab-ab-ab-a`

Comment: @pts do you want to raise this with the luatex developers or do you want us to? (mailing list at luatex [at] tug.org )

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It would be convenient for me if you raised this bug.

Comment: @pts http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2019-January/007030.html